# JWT Authorization token 401 Unauthorize

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, jwt, thephpleague

I was creating a oauth server but I always encountered a 401 Unauthorized error when passing the JWT token to the OAuth2 server. My symfony app version is 6.3.

security.yml

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
    firewalls:
        api_token:
            pattern: ^/api/token$
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            security: true
            stateless: true
            oauth2: true

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            login_throttling:
                max_attempts: 3
                interval: '5 minutes'
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                enable_csrf: true
                default_target_path: app_index
                use_referer: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: app_index

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/authorize, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/login, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/token, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/.well-known, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api, role: ROLE_OAUTH2_EMAIL }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4
                time_cost: 3
                memory_cost: 10
```

API Controller

```
    #[Route('/api/test', name: 'app_api_test')]
    public function apiTest(): Response
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getUser();
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'You successfully authenticated!',
            'email' => $user->getEmail(),
        ]);
    }
```

I've been following the tutorial of dwgebler. Here's the link to the page.

https://davegebler.com/post/php/build-oauth2-server-php-symfony

Thank you.

PS: The symfony version used in the tutorial is v6.1. I think the issue is the version, but I can't pinpoint it with my current understanding.